# Changing TensorFlow operation device placement during runtime?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-xla

As far as I can see, TensorFlow is designed to have fully static device placement across a single `tf.Session.run()`. Is there a known ideal location to insert code for on-the-fly changing of operation device placement?

I'm aware of the static methods at a python level, but I'm looking for something at a C++ level such that I can do something akin to load balancing.

As an example, let's say I want TensorFlow to schedule operations to CPU and GPU in an alternating fashion (hardly ideal, I know). How might I do this at runtime so *as operation dependencies are resolved and more operations are scheduled* the environment of an operation is updated to be a different device? Would this best be done using the [`DeviceMgr`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/38180d7bbc193d5fe63394ac9e994e29097872e8/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/device_mgr.cc) to change execution device for the environment of a given operation in [`ExecutorState::Process(TaggedNode tagged_node, int64 scheduled_usec)`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/38180d7bbc193d5fe63394ac9e994e29097872e8/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc#L1488) right before the operation is launched (line 1651 of `executor.cc`)? Or am I misunderstanding when an operation is scheduled for execution through XLA and when is the latest time I can change the device placement?

Comment: I was looking for this as well. It seemed out of place to decide the device placement when the graph is being constructed. Especially since the `freeze_graph` function/script can be used to clear the device placement metadata. Which means when you later load a saved graph model, you are able to then decide how to place the nodes and edges of the graph on the deployed device.